# Cannot redefine variable when empty in some weblinks (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, syntax

I have a variable (urllinks) that contains a list of links. I use a for loop to go to each link and scrape data, where I collect a nickname and a realname in each link. The code I have below works except that there are some links where there is no nickname and only a realname. In those cases then the css selector of the realname equals the css selector of the nickname (on the links where it had a nickname). I thought if I make a if statement saying that if the realname of each link is empty, then reassign it to the correct definition. However, it did not work. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful

```
for a in urllinks:
        driver.get(a)
        nickname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")

        realname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("subc")
     
    #need to fix the case when there is no nickname and only realname. In those cases
    #realname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")
    if realname is None:
        realname= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")
    for r in range(len(names2)):

        temporarydata4 = {"Main": main[r].text,
                          "Sub": sub[r].text}
        scraperresult2.append(temporarydata4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess several issues are here:

1. `find_elements_by_css_selector` returns a list of web elements. In case there is no match it returns an empty list, but is is still a list, not `None`.
2. to get the element text, I guess this is what you want, you should apply `.text` on returned web element
3. You should use `try-except` and `find_element_by_css_selector` or getting the first element from list if you are using `find_elements_by_css_selector`
   So, I think your code should be something like this:

```
for a in urllinks:
    driver.get(a)
    nickname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")[0].text
    realname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("subc")[].text
     
    if realname is None:
        realname= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")[0].text

    #continue with your code
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @Prophet ! Although I did some modifications to your code, you gave me the intuition by saying it is a list! My answer is below.

Comment: I see. What I don't understand - why did you added your own answer based on my answer? What is the added value there? What is missing in my answer? if my answer resolved your problem - please accept it. Maybe you didn't define clearly what you want to achieve, I answered according to what you asked as well as I could.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed to do using the intuition of @Prophet! Since driver.find.elements_by_css_selector is basically going to store a list. What I did is the following:

```
for a in urllinks:
        driver.get(a)
        nickname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")

        realname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("subc")
     
    #need to fix the case when there is no nickname and only realname. In those 
    cases
    #realname = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")
    if len(realname)==0:
        realname= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mainc")
    for r in range(len(names2)):

        temporarydata4 = {"Main": main[r].text,
                          "Sub": sub[r].text}
        scraperresult2.append(temporarydata4)
```